# I have a problem with preg_match_all function

Tags: php, regex

I dont know how to get full line content from this code.

```php
$str = '

#chapter 1: title 1

content chapter 1 line 1
content chapter 1 line 2
content chapter 1 line 3
content chapter 1 line 4

#chapter 2: title 2

content chapter 2 line 1

';

preg_match_all('/#Chapter ([0-9]+.?[0-9]?)\s?(<([0-9]+)>)?:(.*)(\s+.+\s+)/i',$str, $match);
```

I have tried this code and this get content like this :

$match[5][0]: content chapter 1 line 1

$match[5][1]: content chapter 2 line 2

problem at: (\s+.+\s+).

How can i get full line content ?! Thanks much.

Comment: These examples you have shown _are_ the “full lines”. `content chapter 1 line 1` - that is one _line_ of your input data, after that comes a _different_ line. Do you actually want _all_ the lines after such a `#chapter X: title X` marker?

Comment: Maybe rather try something like `$match = preg_split('/(#Chapter [0-9]+: .*)/i',$str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);` - that gives you the `#chapter x: title x` lines and the following text as two elements each in the resulting array. If you don’t need the title lines in the result, but the chapter contents only, then remove the `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE |` part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you are only matching a single line.

You could use a repeating pattern to match all the lines that do not start with #chapter using a negative lookahead:

`#Chapter\h+\d+:\h+title\h+\d+\K(?:\R(?!#chapter).*)*`

**Explantion**

- `#Chapter` Match literally
- `\h+\d+:` Match 1+ horizontal whitespace chars, 1+ digits and `:`
- `\h+title\h+\d+` Match Match 1+ horizontal whitespace chars, `title`,  match 1+ horizontal whitespace chars and 1+ digits
- `\K` Forget what was matched
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `\R(?!#chapter).*` Match unicode newline sequence and assert what is directly on the right is not #chapter
- `)*` Close on capturing group and repeat 0+ times

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VWGEIK/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/28HL5)

For example:

```
preg_match_all('/#Chapter\h+\d+:\h+title\h+\d+\K(?:\R(?!#chapter).*)*/i',$str, $match);
print_r($match[0]);
```

Result

```
Array
(
    [0] => 

content chapter 1 line 1
content chapter 1 line 2
content chapter 1 line 3
content chapter 1 line 4

    [1] => 

content chapter 2 line 1


)
```